# php check for row count change

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file and in that file right now and it just counts the rows in my database table.

Here is what i'm trying to figure out!

Every-time the row increases by 1, I would like to have it to play a sound effect but every-time it decreases, it will play NO SOUND. Do I use if statement? How would php know that it increased or decreased the number of rows from the last row count!?

If anyone can help (not asking to write to code for me) but if you can guide me in the right direction!

Thanks
Tim

**UPDATE** I can't get this to work. Any help!?

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database_name", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;


//Check for new user
 $test = $_SESSION['number'] = $num_rows;

 if($test > $num_rows ) {
    echo "NEW USER! - PLAY SOUND";
 } else {
    echo "No new user yet :(";
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Save the row count in a session variable. Perform the query, and see if the row count is different from the variable.

Comment: I had the same thought. I was overthinking it after and thinking about a trigger.

Comment: Guys, I updated the post. Maybe you can help me out? Any help is really appreciated! Still trying to get a hand of php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. A little more checks to make this work just like you want:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name", $link);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if(!isset($_SESSION["lastcount"])) {
        $check = $_SESSION['lastcount'] = $num_rows;
    } else {
        $check = $_SESSION['lastcount'];
    }
    echo $num_rows;
     if($num_rows > $check ) { 
        $check = $_SESSION['lastcount'] = $num_rows;
        echo "NEW USER! - PLAY SOUND";
     } else {
        echo "No new user yet :(";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Great! I will study your code learn what you exactly did! Thanks again! Worked perfect!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. I missed the start_session; at the beginning, I hope you added that. Yes take it just an example and do some intelligent checks to make your code's operations more accurate :)